# linux -- determine what service was running on a down port

Tags: linux, bash, application-restart

I need to write a bash script that:

-- takes ip address and list of ports as standard input,

-- check to see if port up or down,

-- if port is down, then restart the service via ssh

Got the first two working, however I am stuck on the last part, determining what service was running on the down port, as I may not know what services the machine is supposed to be running. lsof, netstat are not useful because the service is down.

The assumption is that this script will run on the users machine to check server status and restart any downed services automagically. It is known that some services may use ports listed in /etc/services for other services (for example, cpanel customer portal uses 2083, which /etc/services lists as radsec).

Any help is most appreciated, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to determine what nonstandard ports what a non-running application may have used.  All that you *can* do is to check for services which are not running, and (perhaps) restart those that are not running.

Even doing that runs into problems:

- some services may not be running for other reasons (than loss of connectivity)
- some services may not give a useful status when asked if they are running (Apache Tomcat, for instance, seems to come with service scripts which never do more than half the job).

Comment: I thought this would be the case, but just making sure I wasn't over-looking something. My old school side would insist on figuring out "why" the port was not in the state it should be. So looks like one would have to pass in a file mapping ports to services for each server or something.

Comment: Something like that.  I've only worried about ports when configuring firewalls.  Otherwise, it's usually enough to see if a service is running when it should be or stopped when it should be (for the current runlevel).  A script would be useful for validating that (I do that in paid work, but don't know of a useful free version).